# Help with ODE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the second order IVP:

> $$mu'' + ku' = F_{0} \cos(at)$$

$u(0) = u_{0}; u'(0) = 0.$ Here $m, k, F_{0}, a, u_{0}$ are real constants. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've tried to solve through finding the characteristic equation but can't find an example where there is a coefficient for the second differential.

Comment: If $m \ne 0$ you can assume $m = 1$

Comment: Hmm I thought that but it's not in the question so I wasn't sure

Comment: This is a linear, second order ODE which can be made linear, first order by the change of variable $v = u'$. You can then use an integrating factor, solve for $v$ and then integrate to get $u$.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much Mattos

Comment: Do you think you could write it out for me? I'm still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

One can reduce this second-order linear ODE to a first-order linear ODE by substituting $y(t)=u'(t)$. This gives:
$$my'+ky=F_0\cdot \cos(at) \tag{1}$$
One may put this into the form of a first-order linear differential equation defined as:

> $$\frac{dy}{dt}+P(t)y=Q(t)$$

This is done by dividing both sides by $m$:
$$\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{k}{m}\cdot y=\frac{F_0}{m}\cdot \cos(at) \tag{2}$$
One may solve this using the integrating factor:
$$\mu(t)=e^{\int \frac{k}{m}~dt}=e^{\frac{kt}{m}}$$
Can you continue?